# Selenium UI Testing: TestCleanup() quits rest of the tests after the first test is loaded

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, integration-testing

I am automating my github profile and Following are my test cases:

- Load Browser (this is defined in testInitialize()
- Load Url
- Perform Login
  Below is the code snippet:

namespace GitAutomationTest
    {
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
    using System;
    [TestClass]
        public class GitTest 
        {
            private string baseURL = "https://github.com/login";
            private RemoteWebDriver driver;
            public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

```
     [TestMethod]
     public void LoadURL() {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL);
            Console.Write("Loaded URL is :" + baseURL);
        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void PerformLogin() { 
            driver.FindElementById("login_field").SendKeys("USERNAME");
            driver.FindElementById("password").SendKeys("PASSWORD");
            Console.Write("password entered \n ");
            driver.FindElementByClassName("btn-primary").Click();
            driver.GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile(@"screenshot.jpg", format: System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            Console.Write("Screenshot Saved: screenshiot.jpg");
        }
        [TestCleanup()]
        public void MyTestCleanup()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
        [TestInitialize()]
        public void MyTestInitialize()
        {
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            Console.Write("Maximises The window\n");
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT** 
Everytime I run all tests:
 - Test is initialized : the internet explorer is loaded
 - The base url is loaded
 - Then the driver quits with TestCleanUP()

Next time the driver runs testperformLogin()
 - The test cannot find the username and password elements to perform login, because the base url is not loaded this time.

**How can we manage the TestInitialize() class such that:**
 - browser is up with baseurl until all the tests are completed.
**How can we manage TestCleanup() such that:** 
- browser closes only after all the test are completed.

Comment: Why not to give a try on Nunit testing framework? Please have a look at it. http://nunit.org/index.php?p=docHome&r=2.6.4

Answer (score 0):

There is a `AssemblyCleanup` attribute which runs after all the tests are executed.

You can find more info on attributes here - [Unit Testing Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243147(v=vs.90).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to move following code to "PerformLogin" test method

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL);
```

OR another approach is to add following code at in "Mytestinitialize" method and remove "LoadURL" method

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL);
```

You are facing the issue since [TestInitialize] is called before every [TestMethod] and [TestCleanup] is called after every [TestMethod].

In your case "LoadURL" test is able to get the URL but "PerformLogin" is not able to get the URL since it is not mentioned in "MyTestInitialize".